# Test Observable<Pizza> using Jest in ngRx

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jestjs, angular-observable

I'm trying to create pizzas$ that receive from store and then display that data.

I'm then putting this pizza data on a grid and all looks good.

full code

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ProductesState } from '../shared/models/productesState.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PizzaState } from '../shared/models/pizzaState.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-read',
  templateUrl: './read.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./read.component.css']
})
export class ReadComponent {

  public pizzas$: Observable<PizzaState>;
  private readonly store;

  constructor(private readonly pizzaStore: Store<any>) { 
     this.store = pizzaStore;
     this.getPizzaData();
  }

  public getPizzaData() {
     this.pizzas$ = this.store.select('pizzas');  
  }

}
```

How would i go about testing this component?
I tried the following jest test but it fails with an error

```
this.store.select is not a function
```

test code

```
import { PizzaModel} from '../models/pizza-model';
import { createFakePizza } from '../test-utils/fake-pizza-helper';


    let entityAdapter: EntityAdapter<PizzaModel>;
    let initialEntityState: EntityState<PizzaModel>;    
    let store: any;
...

beforeAll(() => {
      entityAdapter = createEntityAdapter<PizzaModel>();
      initialEntityState = entityAdapter.getInitialState();
    });

describe('getAllPizzas' () => {

  it('should return all pizzas' () => {
   // Arrange
   const fakePizza = [createFakePizza(), createFakePizza()];
   const entityState = entityAdapter.addAll(fakePizza, intialEntityState);

   store = {
    entity: entityState.entities,
   };

  // Act
  const res = new ReadComponent(store);
  res.getPizzaData();


  //Assert
  expect(res.pizzas$).toEqual(fakePizza);

  }

}
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: this.store.select is not a function
```

Please help.
thank you =)

Comment: Could you please try to use the [`select`](https://ngrx.io/api/store/select) operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `select` function to your mock store.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
.....

store = {
  entity: entityState.entities,
  select: () => {
    return of([createFakePizza(), createFakePizza()]);
  },
};
```

You can make `select` return something related to the `entities` but I will leave that to you.